# How to extract value of a latest timestamp from a json using Gson?

Tags: java, json, parsing, sorting, gson

I have a JSON string like this -

```
{"error_1395991841806": "ErrorA", "error_1395991131941": "ErrorB", "error_1395991534713": "ErrorC", "error_1395991772241": "ErrorD"}
```

In the above JSON string, I have all the keys in this format `error_timestampInMilliseconds`.

Now I want to sort all the keys in the descending order of the `timestamp` and then extract the value of that latest `error_timestamp key`. Meaning whatever `timestamp` is the latest as compared to current `timestamp`, I will use that key to extract the value of it. Is this possible to do?

I am using Gson for JSON. Below is my code -

```
String data = new String(event.getData().getData(), Charset.forName("UTF-8"));

// here this data is my json string
System.out.println(data);

JsonObject jsonObject = gson.fromJson(data, JsonObject.class); // parse
```

So suppose if this is the latest timestamp `error_1395991841806` as compared to current timestamp, I will print out `ErrorA` as its value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JSON represents a `Map<String, String>`, and you want to get the highest `Key`, so you may try deserializing your JSON into a [**TreeMap**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html), which is exactly a `Map` sorted by `Key`...

```
Type yourMapType = new TypeToken<TreeMap<String, String>>() {}.getType();
TreeMap<String, String> yourMap = gson.fromJson(yourJsonString, yourMapType);

String highestKey = yourMap.lastKey();
String lastError = yourMap.get(highestKey);
```

Now `lastError` should contain `"ErrorA"`.

Note that I didn't try this, but I guess it should work...

---

***EDIT***: If for some reason you cannot deserialize directly into a `TreeMap` (although I guess you should be able to do it), try deserializing into a generic `Map`, and then construct a `TreeMap` from it, like this:

```
Type yourMapType = new TypeToken<Map<String, String>>() {}.getType();
Map<String, String> yourGenericMap = gson.fromJson(yourJsonString, yourMapType);
TreeMap<String, String> yourMap = new TreeMap<>(yourGenericMap);
// ...
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I was about to try your first suggestion but got confused is the first line starting with `Type`  correct? If yes, then what I am supposed to import for those? This is the first time, I am seeing `Type` and `TypeToken` so got confused

Comment: @SSH, `Type` is a Java built-in interface in the `java.lang.reflect` package. `TypeToken` is a Gson class in the `com.google.gson.reflect` package...

Comment: yeah it works fine but quick question how does it sort the key which is made of `string_timestamp`. Any thoughts?

Comment: @SSH It orders they keys by its *natual ordering*, that's to say, alphabetically in this case. Note that `time_1..1` is *lower than* `time_2..2`. By the way, have you used the first code or the code in the EDIT?